# How do I get the host group of a project collection?

Tags: .net, tfs, lab-management

I'm trying to use the CreateLabEnvironment activity in my workflow. According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934562.aspx) I need to supply the TeamProjectHostGroupName argument, which is a "Host group where the new environment will be deployed. If the specified host group is not found, a NoTeamProjectHostGroupFoundException exception is thrown. Required."

How do I get the host group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host group is specified in the configuration for lab management on the TFS server and your administrator can tell you what it is.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386364.aspx